# Cómo subir una imagen con struts 2.0.11?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Estoy tratando de jugar con archivos en struts. Me he basado aquí:
https://danielme.com/tip-struts2-01-subida-de-ficheros/

Pero no logro hacerlo, me marca error siempre que envío un s:file de strtus hacia el action.

El código es exactamente como el ejemplo que pongo en el link.

Saben si se debe a la versión de Struts? y si es así cómo y qué puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Y si mencionas el tipo de error que recibes?

Comment: No servirá de nada, es un error 500 el que me sale. No hay un error en específico, simplemente no sé porqué no puedo trabajar con el s:file. Cuando le doy a enviar al formulario me manda a una pantalla con error 500 interno y ya, en la consola de mi servidor no marca nada y aunque le ponga una línea de log comenzando el método que se va a ejecutar cuando manda el formulario no lo imprime.

Comment: -.-!, Cómo sabes que no sirve de nada, 500= Error internal server, algo trono y por ende hay una traza, si no ves algo en  la consola, segun tu appServer, busca el log del servidor.